# how to check if ng-init is processed without using $scope in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Html code

```
<div ng-controller = "ctrl as ct">
 <input type="text" ng-model="ct.recentTurn" ng-init = "ct.recentTurn="555">
</div>
```

Angular Code

```
(function() {
  angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", mainCtrl);
  mainCtrl.$inject =["$scope"];
  function mainCtrl($scope){
     var ctrl = this;
     console.log(this.recentTurn); // this give undefined
     $scope.$watch("ct.recentTurn", function(old, newv){
       console.log(old);
       console.log(newv);
       //these two give correct value 555.
     });
}
})();
```

I want to call a function when controller is loaded with parameter recentTurn, but when controller is loaded recentTurn is not defined&initialized as i wanted. Value recentTurn will be thrown from server. Using `$scope.$watch` function would solve the issue, but i want to avoid using $scope. So is there anyway i could find when ng-init initialize the variable?

Comment: why don't you initialize ct.recentTurn in your controller?

Comment: @NTP I am trying to inject the constant via serer-side script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your variable is undefined in the controller body is because a controller-function acts as a constructor. This constructor is called whenever the controller's scope is created, which in your case is when `<div ng-controller="ctrl as ct">` is compiled and the controller's scope is bound to the DOM.

Since your `ng-init` is nested within the `ng-controller` directive, it will be bound (and thus evaluated) after the controller constructor function has been called. This means your line

```
console.log(this.recentTurn); // this give undefined
```

is called before the expression in `ng-init` is evaluated.

Using `ng-init` for initializing simple variables may be considered bad practice, since you're basically placing application logic in your template/view. This is undesirable. There are actually very few usecases where `ng-init` is considered a valid, which you can [read more about in the documentation (the big red warning box)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). Instead of using `ng-init` you should simply initialize the variable in your controller.

Comment: My case is actually the third one "injecting data via server side scripting".
If i use `ng-init` outside controller `ct`, can i access the variable within controller?

Comment: Alright, well that's a valid case then. For that particular case, what I like to do instead, is to inject a constant into Angular within a script tag. Like this: `<script>angular.constant('SOME_CONSTANT', { 'some_value': @Model.SomeProperty });</script>` this is particularly useful when you have several variables - or an entire object - to inject using server side scripting. If it's only one variable I'd stick with `ng-init` and then work around it not being ready when the controller is created.

Comment: If you need to call something that relies on your variable being set, you can use the `ctrl.$postLink = function(){}` controller lifecycle hook to do things. That is called after `ng-init` is evaluated (since it evaluates in the pre-link phase).